# Is a 1.8v supply too low for driving a long bus?

Tags: power-supply, noise

I'm designing a circuit comprised of two boards separated 23 inches away and connected through a ribbon cable which carries an I2C bus (400Khz) and various interrupt digital signals, plus VCC and GND.

Since it's a battery powered device I initially chose a supply of 1.8v (which is the minimum common voltage between the various ICs), but after reading some white papers I realised that such low supply could be way too prone to pick noise for such a long bus. A possible solution is to increase the supply to 2.5v or even 3v, but I would like to be sure since I would loose around a 25% of battery life.

So the question is, is a 1.8v supply too low considering the length of the bus? And if so, would 2.5v be enough?

Comment: Powering the remote board through the bus does not sound like a great idea.

Comment: Umm, well, I need to power the remote board someway, and the ribbon is capable of carrying up to 0.5A per wire and I just need 5mA on the remote board. I don't really see the problem here :S

Comment: So add some filtering? Not sure what the problem is?

Comment: @MattYoung, you mean to the VCC signal? If so, I'm afraid I haven't explained myself well...My concern is the noise on the  bus digital signals, not into VCC itself.

Comment: Powering 5ma should be OK as long as you have enough decoupling on the far end. Bus noise .. depends very much on how noisy the environment is. You should at minimum put a ground between every two signal wires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In I2C, it is typically the "1" that is noise prone due to the RC/pull-up.  You can make the channel more robust by increasing the pull-up strength (i.e., reduce R value).  You could also place a pull-up on both ends of the line.  Another idea might be to run your logic at 1.8V, but have your pull-ups referenced to a higher voltage to give you better noise immunity.  Do you need to run at 400kHz?  Could you accomplish the same task with a lower clock rate?  If you are using ribbon cable, interleaving GND will go a long way to alleviating noise in low-speed digital.  It also gives you better impedance control.

What aggressor circuits are nearby?  What environment is this going into?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I need those 400Khz. My idea was to place grounds on both edges of the cable and interleaved between VCC and the slow digital lines and then between the former and the I2C lines. Something like: GND-SDA-SCL-GND-*SLOW DIGITAL*-GND-VCC-GND. Regarding the environment, it is going to be used outdoors, on a garden, placed between wooden planks. Thank you!

Comment: I'd flop the left-most GND and SDA, but even that probably won't matter.  You'll be fine at 1.8V, 400kHz.  I've run 2.5V I2C over several meters of ribbon carrying high edge rate signals on the same cable.

Comment: Thank you @M D, that's the kind of experience I was looking for.